# Running e2e tests in headless safari using nightwatch

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, safaridriver

I have writing e2e tests to be run in headless mode in all the major browsers like chrome, safari, firefox. Headless mode is working fine on chrome and firefox but not working on safari. When i ran my tests it opens the safari browser everytime.

I have tried safari options like :

- "args" : ["headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"] and
- "args" : ["--headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"] and
- "args" : ["-headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"]

  in nightwatch.json. But all this options are not working in my case.

My safari object i'm defining in my nightwatch.json is :-

```
"safari": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "safari",
        "safariOptions" : {
          "args" : ["--headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"]
       }
      }
    }
```

But above configuration is not working. I have already searched all the related articles on github and stackoverflow for this. But all the efforts goes in vain.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5):

After doing more googling regarding my above issue, i'm able to figure out that right now headless mode is not supported in safari browser.
For More info visit this link :- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5985